# Jenkins + Maven + TestNG = MojoFailureException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

When I run in `Eclipse`, `Maven` and `TestNG` work fine and pass, but when I run in `Jenkins`, the following failure message appears:

> MojoFailureException
>   Unlike many other errors, this exception is not generated by the Maven core itself but by a plugin. As a rule of thumb, plugins use this error to signal a failure of the build because there is something wrong with the dependencies or sources of a project, e.g. a compilation or a test failure.
>   The concrete meaning of the exception depends on the plugin so please have a look at its documentation. The documentation for many common Maven plugins can be reached via our plugin index.

This is my pom.xml:

```css
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.techbeamers</groupId>
    <artifactId>loadtesting</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Load Testing</name>
    <description>Selenium Load Testing Example using TestNG and Maven</description>
    <properties>
        <selenium.version>2.53.1</selenium.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.10</testng.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Below plug-in is used to execute tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <!-- Include the following dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>   
</project>
```

Please help -- I don't know what's wrong with my `plugin` or `dependencies`.

Comment: also here is Jenkins console output: [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: and this is maven output: T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 12.414 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: Why do you have a maven-plugin (maven-compiler-plugin) as a dependency ? This is simply wrong...Furthermore it would be helpful if you could past the whole error output cause there is much more on the console in Jenkins and read the output carefully...

Answer (score 0):

The first possible problem I see: you define the property: `testng.version`, set the value to: `6.9.10`, but then ignore the `testng.version` property later in your `pom.xml`, and set the `<version>` of `TestNG` to: `6.8`.

Try changing the definition of your `TestNG` `<dependency>` from what you curently have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

So that the definition is defined as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>${testng.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```